# How can I check if DELETE is pressed on a ListView with .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net

My event handler looks like this:

```
private void List_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

I saw on a msdn thread, the following solution:

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
```

But, in this version of .net, the KeyPressEventArgs doesn't have a KeyCode property. How should I handle the delete in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the KeyDown event instead:

```
private void List_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        // your delete code goes here
    }
}
```

This isn't limited to just .NET 2.0, in all .NET versions `KeyPressEventArgs` does not have a `.KeyCode` see: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx), so you have to use KeyDown instead.